# a parallelism problem - the most interesting garment

Tags: parallelism

Is there a parallelism issue with the following sentence?

> Prize money will be given to the best dressed, the worst dressed, and the most “interesting” garment.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem. The final item should be *and the most "interestingly" dressed.*

Comment: As stated, the sentence suggests that the prize money will go to the garments rather than their wearers. To avoid this suggestion, you might write: *Prize money will be given to the best dressed, the worst dressed and the most interestingly dressed party-goers, (guests, entrants or whatever)*. Or, *To guests in the best dressed, worst dressed and most interestingly dressed categories.* If you want to keep *garments*, you might say that the money will *be awarded for*.

Comment: @RonaldSole Are you saying that the OP sentence would be OK if the preposition "to" is replaced by "for"? Why? The best-dressed and the worst-dressed refer to people, whereas the most interesting garment refers to a garment. Would it be natural to put them together?

Comment: @Apollyon Perfectly true. I should have spotted that myself!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a parallelism issue with the following sentence?

The sentence sounds like you're giving away 3 prizes.  If you meant this, your sentence works.

> and the most “interesting” garment.

While if analyzed closely this does literally mean you're giving money to the garment, since you mention "dressed" twice, you establish a pattern and it's obvious you mean "one who is wearing the most interesting garment."

Comment: If your account works, then you should expect "The best dressed will receive $500, the worst dressed $200, and the most interesting garment $150" to be correct. But is that really the case?